# Vertical marquee with continuous loop but overlapping text on flexible height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, marquee

I have a vertical marquee that works great if you have the height of the parent div set to a fixed height. However I need mine to be `80vh` and be responsive, which means I can't have a fixed height. This causes the text to show to soon and start overlapping and go out of order.

I think the issue I'm having is that the `top` is set to `100` and not a `%` but I'm not sure how to correct this issue?

They're numbered and boxed to show the overlapping and spacing issue.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6qg31xm/)

Below is a working example of the issue.

```js
window.verticalScroller = function($elem) {
    var top = parseInt($elem.css("top"));
    var temp = -1 * $('.js-cycle-list > li').height();
    if(top < temp) {
        top = $('.js-cycle-list').height()
        $elem.css("top", top);
    }
    $elem.animate({ top: (parseInt(top)-100) }, 600, 'linear', function () {
      window.verticalScroller($(this))
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $(".js-cycle-list > li").each(function () {
          $(this).css("top", i);
          i += 100;
          window.verticalScroller($(this));
    });
});
```

```css
.cycle-text {
    height: 80vh;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
}

.cycle__list {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.cycle__list li {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cycle__list li p {
  color: #f40000;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cycle-text ">
        <ul class="cycle__list js-cycle-list o-pd-top-md o-pd-btm-md">
            <li>
                <p>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>7. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>8. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>9. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>10. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>11. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>12. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>13. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>14. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>15. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>16. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>17. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>18. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>19. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>20. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>21. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>22. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>23. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>24. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>25. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>26. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>27. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>28. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>29. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
          <li>
                <p>30. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, I fixed the height of `li` parent element with `JS` and made it equal to the sum of the `li` elements. Like this when you set `top = $('.js-cycle-list').height()` It really goes to the end of the div, because if you set a fixed value like `80vh` the sum of `li` height could be more than `80vh` and this causes the text to show overlapping and go out of order.
I hope I explained this well, This is my demo updated:

```js
window.verticalScroller = function($elem) {
    var top = parseInt($elem.css("top"));
    var temp = -1 * $('.js-cycle-list > li').height();
    if(top < temp) {
        top = $('.js-cycle-list').height()
        $elem.css("top", top);
    }
    $elem.animate({ top: (parseInt(top)-100) }, 600, 'linear', function () {
      window.verticalScroller($(this))
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    // get total height of li elements
    var ulHeight = 0;
    $(".js-cycle-list > li").each(function () {
      ulHeight = ulHeight + $(this).height();
    });
    $('.js-cycle-list').css("height", ulHeight - 200);
    
    $(".js-cycle-list > li").each(function () {
          $(this).css("top", i);
          i += 100;
          window.verticalScroller($(this));
    });
});
```

```css
.cycle-text {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cycle__list {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.cycle__list li {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cycle__list li p {
  color: #f40000;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: left
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cycle-text ">
        <ul class="cycle__list js-cycle-list o-pd-top-md o-pd-btm-md">
            <li>
                <p>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>7. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>8. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>9. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>10. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>11. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>12. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>13. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>14. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>15. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>16. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>17. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>18. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>19. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>20. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>21. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>22. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>23. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>24. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>25. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>26. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>27. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>28. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>29. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>30. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for this but its not longer looping through. Once it's gone through the list its no longer cycling through and showing the first LI again. It just stops

Comment: Hi @probablybest I Fixed the issue I did an update and updated my explanation, please take a look at it.